# Deserializing complex json object with dictionary

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Newtonsoft Json.Net to deserialize json feed into object:

Json:

```
staticKey1: value,
staticKey2: value,

results: [
{
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2,
   key3: value3,
...
   keyN: valueN
}
],
```

C# class:

```
public class MyClassName
{
    public string staticKey1 { get; set; }
    public string staticKey2 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, String> results { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(), but I'm getting exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its easy, use:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string staticKey1 { get; set; }
    public string staticKey2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> results { get; set; }
}
```

But maybe there's better solution.